# Can add cookies to image control in WP7

Tags: image, windows-phone-7, cookies, uri

I am displaying image by  setting the source of an Image element directly to an URI.
Like  
But for security purpose now the URI has a cookie attached with it.
Can someone please tell me if it is possible to attach cookie to a URI and display it in an image control in WP7?.

Thanks,
Kanaya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to download the image with WebClient and then assign the image directly after downloading it.

Comment: Thanks Shawn for a quick reply. So there is no way without downloading the image.

Comment: Nope...no way but WebClient...You could create an attached property to centralize it though.